# An example of the "natural" paring $V^* \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

This so called natural paring is not natural to me at all. I am wonder if someone could give me an explicit example?

I understand that $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$, and to my understanding, its basis is $f^*$, which are row vectors looks like $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what $V^*$ is?

Comment: Oh yes, the dual space of $V$.

Comment: $(f,x)\mapsto f(x)$

Comment: And do you know what "dual space" means?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Not very much. To my understanding, the basis of dual space is $f^*$, which are row vectors looks like $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$.

Comment: Thanks @Norbert, but how about $T^k_l$, while $k \neq l$?

Comment: what is $T_l^k$?

Comment: @Norbert When I have $k$ element from $V^*$, but a different number of element from $V$. May be the element form $V^*$ not necessarily eat 1 element from $V$?

Comment: sorry still do not understand

Comment: I would try to avoid thinking about bases, at least at the beginning. It's true that if you pick a basis for $V$ _and the corresponding dual basis for_ $V^*$ then you do have row vectors multiplying column vectors to get a number but the pairing is much more natural than that, and makes sense even when $V$ is not finite dimensional.

Comment: @Norbert sorry, I mean, I would like an example of, say, $V^* \times V \times V$ and $V^* \times V^* \times V$.

Comment: For larger combinations of $V$ and $V^*$ you can "contract" two chosen factors, e.g., $V^* \times V \times V \to V$ given by $(f, u, v) \mapsto f(u)v$. These are also called traces because they coincide [somehow] with the trace map on $\operatorname{End}(V)$ if we identify $\operatorname{End}(V) \cong V^* \otimes V$.

Comment: Thank you @TTS, that is very inspiring. But I am very intrigued by your reference to contract/trace. Would you mind kindly explaining that why it coincide with the trace? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, if $V$ is a vector space (forget about it having a basis) over a field $k$, then the dual space $V^*$ is the space of linear functionals $f\colon V\to k$. Thus the most natural thing to do if you have a linear functional $f\in V^*$ and a vector $v\in V$, is to take $f(v)$. This gives you the natural pairing $V^*\times V\to k$, $(f,v)\mapsto f(v)$.

Comment: Thank you! How about when I have $k$ element from $V^*$, but a different number of element from $V$. May be the element form $V^*$ not necessarily eat 1 element from $V$? Like an example of $V^* \times V \times V$ and $V^* \times V^* \times V$.